# pkgbuild open URL using default browser

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, zsh

I use `pkgbuild` to create an Apple installer `.pkg`.

In my `preinstall` script, I have the following, which opens in Chrome if I invoke it myself, however when run by `pkgbuild` script, always opens the above link using Safari:

```
open "https://apple.stackexchange.com/"
```

I tried to force it to run as the current user:

```
sudo -u "$(logname || echo "$SUDO_USER")" open "https://apple.stackexchange.com/"
```

... but it still uses Safari.

My system default is currently Chrome.  I changed it to Firefox, and the same thing occurs.

How do I open this URL using the default browser within a `pkgbuild` script?

Comment: The installer context doesn’t know about your default browser and will always use Safari because that is all it knows about

Comment: Does the package require administrator rights?

Comment: @GrahamMiln yes, the `.pkg` will run as `root` by default.  What wasn't obvious was the `logname` and `$SUDO_USER` were not working.  Adapting some hints on another thread, I was able to find that `sudo -u $USER` did the trick.  The solution is posted below,.

Answer (score 1):

After echoing some values of `preinstall` to a temp file and some advice from comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619036/, I found the following:

- `$SUDO_USER` is empty
- `logname` is `root`
- ✅`$USER` has the correct value

So adopting the script as follows fixes it.  The link is opened in the default browser.

```
sudo -u "$USER" open "https://apple.stackexchange.com/"
```

As an aside, the following I had expected to work but it **DID NOT** work.  This technique still opens in Safari, unfortunately.

```
su "$USER" -c "open https://apple.stackexchange.com"
```

So, use `sudo -u "$USER"` and it should work.